# Why won't the JavaScript code work out of codepen.io

Tags: javascript, html, css

So there is some code from codepen.io http://codepen.io/karolpodlesny/pen/npKqu. It is uploaded here: http://fredricarms.com/javatestindex.html.

Now, the HTML, CSS and JavaScript for making the boxes expand and do all the cool things, are working how they are supposed to, being in separate files, so is the modernizr. I also the know that the js is being called because in the boxlayout.js I wrote some code to bring up and alert box and it worked just fine. So I am guessing that codepen fixes the code so it runs perfectly. I just don't know what is wrong with the code in the boxlayout.js that is not working on my server. Please help and thank you so much. Below is the code in the boxlayout js file.

```
var Boxlayout = (function() {
    var $el = $( '#bl-main' ),
        $sections = $el.children( 'section' ),
        // works section
        $sectionWork = $( '#bl-work-section' ),
        // work items
        $workItems = $( '#bl-work-items > li' ),
        // work panels
        $workPanelsContainer = $( '#bl-panel-work-items' ),
        $workPanels = $workPanelsContainer.children( 'div' ),
        totalWorkPanels = $workPanels.length,
        // navigating the work panels
        $nextWorkItem = $workPanelsContainer.find( 'nav > span.bl-next-work' ),
        // if currently navigating the work items
        isAnimating = false,
        // close work panel trigger
        $closeWorkItem = $workPanelsContainer.find( 'nav > span.bl-icon-close' ),
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition' : 'transitionend',
            'OTransition' : 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition' : 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition' : 'transitionend'
        },
        // transition end event name
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        // support css transitions
        supportTransitions = Modernizr.csstransitions;

    function init() {
        initEvents();
    }

    function initEvents() {

        $sections.each( function() {

            var $section = $( this );

            // expand the clicked section and scale down the others
            $section.on( 'click', function() {

                if( !$section.data( 'open' ) ) {
                    $section.data( 'open', true ).addClass( 'bl-expand bl-expand-top' );
                    $el.addClass( 'bl-expand-item' );   
                }

            } ).find( 'span.bl-icon-close' ).on( 'click', function() {

                // close the expanded section and scale up the others
                $section.data( 'open', false ).removeClass( 'bl-expand' ).on( transEndEventName, function( event ) {
                    if( !$( event.target ).is( 'section' ) ) return false;
                    $( this ).off( transEndEventName ).removeClass( 'bl-expand-top' );
                } );

                if( !supportTransitions ) {
                    $section.removeClass( 'bl-expand-top' );
                }

                $el.removeClass( 'bl-expand-item' );

                return false;

            } );

        } );

        // clicking on a work item: the current section scales down and the respective work panel slides up
        $workItems.on( 'click', function( event ) {

            // scale down main section
            $sectionWork.addClass( 'bl-scale-down' );

            // show panel for this work item
            $workPanelsContainer.addClass( 'bl-panel-items-show' );

            var $panel = $workPanelsContainer.find("[data-panel='" + $( this ).data( 'panel' ) + "']");
            currentWorkPanel = $panel.index();
            $panel.addClass( 'bl-show-work' );

            return false;

        } );

        // navigating the work items: current work panel scales down and the next work panel slides up
        $nextWorkItem.on( 'click', function( event ) {

            if( isAnimating ) {
                return false;
            }
            isAnimating = true;

            var $currentPanel = $workPanels.eq( currentWorkPanel );
            currentWorkPanel = currentWorkPanel < totalWorkPanels - 1 ? currentWorkPanel + 1 : 0;
            var $nextPanel = $workPanels.eq( currentWorkPanel );

            $currentPanel.removeClass( 'bl-show-work' ).addClass( 'bl-hide-current-work' ).on( transEndEventName, function( event ) {
                if( !$( event.target ).is( 'div' ) ) return false;
                $( this ).off( transEndEventName ).removeClass( 'bl-hide-current-work' );
                isAnimating = false;
            } );

            if( !supportTransitions ) {
                $currentPanel.removeClass( 'bl-hide-current-work' );
                isAnimating = false;
            }

            $nextPanel.addClass( 'bl-show-work' );

            return false;

        } );

        // clicking the work panels close button: the current work panel slides down and the section scales up again
        $closeWorkItem.on( 'click', function( event ) {

            // scale up main section
            $sectionWork.removeClass( 'bl-scale-down' );
            $workPanelsContainer.removeClass( 'bl-panel-items-show' );
            $workPanels.eq( currentWorkPanel ).removeClass( 'bl-show-work' );

            return false;

        } );

    }

    return { init : init };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code relies entirely on jQuery, however you haven't included jQuery on your live site. On your CodePen example you're using jQuery 1.9.1:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

You can continue to use the Google-hosted version, or if you want to host it yourself you can download jQuery from [jQuery's own website](http://jquery.com/download/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to initialize your BoxLayout once your document has finished loading (all those `jQuery` variables you're using inside your library won't be defined because their equivalent dom elements are not yet rendered), that's why you need to init everything when dom is ready.

Add this line of code to the bottom of your `boxlayout.js` file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Boxlayout.init();
});
```

Just for testing purposes, open up the web developer console on your website, and run this js code:

```
Boxlayout.init();
```

You'll see everything will work just fine.